# Does anyone know why system and console isn't working here?

Tags: c#, sdk

```
using System;

using SplashKitSDK;

public class Program
{
public static void Main()
{
    console.WriteLine("Hello World");
}
}
```

**Some of the errors I am getting:**

> Unnecessary using directive. [Helloworld]csharp(CS8019)
> The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a
> using
> directive or an assembly reference?) [Helloworld, Helloworld, Helloworld,
> Helloworld]csharp(CS0246)

> Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported

> The name 'Console' does not exist in the current context

I've tried everything, and nothing seems to work. I also believe I installed the language tools and library correctly. If anyone knows how to fix this please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "not working", give us some useful details please. Also C# is case sensitive so you should have `Console.WriteLine`

Comment: Sorry, so the program is meant to be a simple display of the text 'Hello World' I have installed netcore sdk, splashkit library

Comment: It appears as though I have a number of errors also present in the vs code folder (obj, netcore app5.0, and library)

Comment: It's with capital `C`. `Console`

Comment: Maybe `mscorlib` is not referenced? Not sure if that's possible

Comment: I'll check it out and let you guys know. Thanks for the advice and help! Cheers